# What's the limit of a variable in T-SQL? Why does my variable prints out as NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I'm creating a stored procedure with the following code:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE Insert_Into_Table
    @Origin VARCHAR(255),
    @Destination VARCHAR(255),
    @Origin_Columns VARCHAR (4000),
    @Destination_Columns VARCHAR (4000),
    @Delete_Date_Column_Name VARCHAR(63), --Nullable
    @Delete_Period_Months INT -- Nullable
AS
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @insert_query VARCHAR(4000) = NULL;
        DECLARE @delete_query VARCHAR(4000) = NULL;
        DECLARE @check_query VARCHAR (4000) = NULL;
        DECLARE @Date_To_Delete DATETIME = CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -@Delete_Period_Months, GETDATE()) AS DATETIME);

        -- Table names cannot be referenced directly in SPs, so we bypass
        -- this issue by declaring a variable containing the query
        IF @Delete_Date_Column_Name IS NOT NULL 
           OR @Delete_Period_Months IS NOT NULL
           SET @delete_query = 'DELETE FROM ' + @Destination + ' WHERE ' +
            @Delete_Date_Column_Name + ' >= ' + CONCAT(CHAR(39),CAST(@Date_To_Delete AS VARCHAR(255)),CHAR(39));
        ELSE
            PRINT N'Missing or no values provided for table deletion. Only executing copy';

        CREATE TABLE #temptable (count INT)

        SET @check_query = 'INSERT INTO #temptable SELECT TOP 1 1 AS count FROM ' + @Origin
        EXECUTE(@check_query)

        SET @insert_query = 'INSERT INTO' + QUOTENAME(@Destination) + QUOTENAME(@Destination_Columns, '()') +
        'SELECT ' + @Origin_Columns + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Origin);

        BEGIN TRY
            IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #temptable)
            BEGIN TRANSACTION        
                EXECUTE(@delete_query);
                EXECUTE(@insert_query);
                COMMIT
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                ROLLBACK;
                THROW 51000, 'The Origin table is empty', 1;
            END CATCH
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        THROW 51000, 'Error creating transaction', 1;
    END CATCH
GO
```

When executing the stored proecedure with the parameters shown, it works correctly:

```
EXEC Insert_Into_Table
        @Origin = 'Sink_Proc',
        @Destination = 'Sink_Test',
        @Origin_Columns = 'customer, order_number, created_date',
        @Destination_Columns = 'customer, order_number, created_date',
        @Delete_Date_Column_Name = NULL,
        @Delete_Period_Months = NULL
```

However, when executing it with 25+ columns as Origin/Destination columns, when I print the @insert_query variable, it returns NULL and no operation is done. Why is this happening?

Comment: As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments), `quotename` returns `null` for inputs longer than 128 characters. Concatenating `null` with a string results in `null`. The function is designed for single names, not several at once. It would not correctly escape braces if you had them in the middle of your names anyway.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you! You were absolutely right. Updating to CONCAT did the work.

Comment: You should fix other issues with that procedure too. All object names must be `nvarchar`. The delete query must use `quotename` for `@Destination` and `@Delete_Date_Column_Name`, and accept `@Date_To_Delete` as a variable via `sp_executesql`, not have it concatenated in. The temp table should be replaced with a `bit` variable set by an `exists` query. Both `@Destination_Columns` and `@Origin_Columns` must be split at commas (which is not trivial if they contain commas in themselves which is legal) and have `quotename` applied to each bit individually.

Comment: This procedure is problematic from start to finish. It is wide open to sql injection. It seems like a rethinking/redesign would be the best approach going forward.

Comment: @GSerg Indeed there's much space for improvement, this stored procedure is still work in progress. I really appreciate all your suggestions which I'll definitely take them in account while refactoring the code.

Comment: @SeanLange While developing this procedure, SQL Injection prevention wasn't a priority because of how we plan to execute it. Nonetheless, it's important to not leave it open for that. What specific suggestions would you give to improve it?

Comment: Odd that `'INSERT INTO' + QUOTENAME(@Destination) + QUOTENAME(@Destination_Columns, '()') + 'SELECT '` doesn't have spaces between pieces/parts. Has the outermost `try`/`catch` caught anything? It's a shame that the `catch` block hides any details.

Comment: As I said before it needs to be completely rethought from the beginning. Passing in an object name for a procedure like this is never going to work out well as it is nearly impossible to prevent sql injection when the code munges up a big string and executes it.

Comment: @HABO Actually yes, the outer `try/catch` block has caught many exceptions during debugging

Comment: Would it be unacceptable for security or other reasons to put something like `declare @Message as NVarChar(2048) = N'Error creating transaction: ''' + Error_Message() + N''' (' + Cast( Error_Number() as NVarChar(6) ) + N') perceived at line ' + Cast( Error_Line() as NVarChar(6) ) + N'. Have a nice day!'; throw 51000, @Message, 1;` in the `catch` block? It may overwhelm end users, but can make debugging and maintenance rather easier.

Comment: @HABO Actually we're just a bunch of engineers so the end user would really appreciate it lol. To be honest, I haven't dived deep enough into error handling and reporting in SQL and this just feels like gold. If you got any recommendations about it, it would be awesome.